# count everytime and update a field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have three tables here :
[image: Table1]

The data is for three persons for three weeks:week1,week2 and week3.I have modified the table and created a new field i.e the Level_Field.So ,it has null value now.

Now I have the data for the new week i.e week4 (below table).It has one more person i.e person 4.Whenever there is a new person ,I want to update the level_field with output of this division of two field's value :pointsRewarded / hours .(pointsRewarded divided by Hours)

[image]
If no  new employee in the data  it should just show something as 'no new employee' .For instance,for week5 no new employee joins .So it should show:
[image]

**I want to write a GENERALIZED query where it checks current week count of no of employee to last week's count of total no of employee and fulfill the above condition.**

Is it possible to have a generalized query ?

Please help me with the query or any suggestion .

Thanks a lot,anyone who contributes.

Comment: Can you explain why you have a new table every week?  And why if you have a column named weeknumber, is it not just an integer?  And why you don't have one column for medal and just have a gold, silver or bronze in there?  And you shouldn't need a column that calculates it's value based on two other fields in the table, that can be done in a select.  And you shouldn't double up the use of a column, the column should store that average data OR it should store whether the employee is new this week but not both.

Comment: hey , thanks for the response.I have a new table every week coz it will be new data which will be imported to the original  table at database.I will have a new table for each of the 52 weeks of the year.The column level_field should store the value after division if there is a new person for the week,Else  only a comment would be displayed such as 'no new person'

Comment: And I think you've misunderstood, you should store data if needed and present data as needed.  That column (IMO) should be used only to indicate if the employee is new (for that week).  Then when you select the data from the table, you can use a CASE statement that says if there is a new employee, then calculate the points/hours.